# How to operate and choose the right components to control an industrial pull and push solenoid using an Arduinuo?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, diodes, solenoid

Push/Pull which has a 24 V DC power supply and  power consumption of 23/85/400 W.

What transistor and diode configs I should be going for?

Comment: do you have a datasheet for that solenoid? as well as what your application is

Comment: More information is needed and links to the data sheet. Consider a N-Channel MOSFET.  It will run much cooler at the higher wattages. Depending on the ambient, MOSFET etc you may get by without a large heat sink. With a transistor you will need a heat sink.

Comment: https://bensonsolenoids.co.uk/dc-latching-solenoids/. It's the last one in the website. BLM5